# Shell: Adding property in XML element if the attribute is not present

Tags: xml, shell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to write a Chef Recipe to add a property to my XML attribute if the attribute is not present and set the value if the attribute exists.

**xml_file**:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="false" />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I want to add a new attribute `SSLEnabled="true"` for each Connector tag if the SSLEnabled key is not present. And Update the value to "true" if the attribute already exists.

Can I consider using shell commands (preferably grep/sed/awk)??

If not, Which resource would be appropriate for this usecase?

**P.S**: My Connector XML tag can be spanned to multiple lines or in a single line.

Comment: You should not prefer a regex-based tool for processing XML.

Comment: We do not recommend using this kind of partial update workflow with config files in Chef. It's better to make the whole file controlled by a `template` resource or similar, since that ensures the system is always convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
xmlstarlet ed --insert '//Connector[not(@SSLEnabled)]' \
              --type attr --name 'SSLEnabled' --value "true" \
           file.xml
```

To save the output into the same file, add the `--inplace` option after the `ed` subcommand.